# How to make reset/clear radio button JS but except 1 radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanna make 4 lines of radio buttons
line 1, line 2, line 3 and last line

if i click reset button
the radio button back to its normal choice(check or uncheck)
but i wanna make the line 1 doesnt affected(not reset)
since this script reset/clear all radio button

thank you

```js
$('#reset').on('click', function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', function() {
    return this.getAttribute('checked') == 'checked';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="rdo1" value="a" checked="checked" /> A
      <input type="radio" name="rdo1" value="b" /> B
      <input type="radio" name="rdo1" value="c" /> C
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="rdo2" value="1" /> 1
      <input type="radio" name="rdo2" value="2" checked="checked" /> 2
      <input type="radio" name="rdo2" value="3" /> 3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="rdo3" value="1a" /> 1a
      <input type="radio" name="rdo3" value="2b" /> 2b
      <input type="radio" name="rdo3" value="3c" checked="checked" /> 3c
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="rdo4" value="11a" /> 1a
      <input type="radio" name="rdo4" value="12b" /> 2b
      <input type="radio" name="rdo4" value="13c" /> 3c
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this one is working thanks :)

Comment: I suppose I should've made it an answer. Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that by getting the name or use the `.not` selector too

```
$('#reset').on('click', function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', function () {
        var rdoName = $(this).attr('name');
        if(rdoName != 'rdo1'){
            return this.getAttribute('checked') == 'checked';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the line one is getting reset, i dont want it reset.
still check but no reset/uncheck (the line 1's position not move if i click reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/) or [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to exclude the ones you don't want to reset:

```
$('input[type=radio]').not('[name="rdo1"]').prop('checked', function () {
    return this.getAttribute('checked') == 'checked';
});
```

Expand and run the following snippet to see it in context.

```js
$('#reset').on('click', function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').not('[name="rdo1"]').prop('checked', function () {
        return this.getAttribute('checked') == 'checked';
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="rdo1" value="a" checked="checked" />
                A
                <input type="radio" name="rdo1" value="b" />
                B
                <input type="radio" name="rdo1" value="c" />
                C
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="rdo2" value="1" />
                1
                <input type="radio" name="rdo2" value="2" checked="checked" />
                2
                <input type="radio" name="rdo2" value="3" />
                3
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="rdo3" value="1a" />
                1a
                <input type="radio" name="rdo3" value="2b"  />
                2b
                <input type="radio" name="rdo3" value="3c" checked="checked" />
                3c
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="rdo4" value="11a" />
                1a
                <input type="radio" name="rdo4" value="12b"  />
                2b
                <input type="radio" name="rdo4" value="13c"/>
                3c
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="reset">Reset</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```